# Range of a java statement

Tags: java, random, range

just a quick question. I'm pretty new to programming and I'm having trouble figuring out what the range of  `e = rand.nextInt(10) * 4` would be. Can someone please help me out? I've already tried all the obvious answers and they weren't right.

Comment: The result will be between 0 and 36, and will be a multiple of 4.

Comment: see documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive).

---

`nextInt(10)` will return a random number within the range of `0-9` because the number `10` is exclusive, therefore that times `4` will return a range of `0-36`.

Like @Jesper mentioned it will be multiples of `4`, so `0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36`.

Comment: Another important detail is that the resulting number will always be a multiple of 4 - so it will, for example, never be 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, etc.